# Can selection in one input field of Formik drive DOM creation in another input field of Formik?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, formik

Steps: User makes a selection in the first question of the form. The resulting answer will be used to build a series of checkboxes as the 2nd question of the form.

I was able to get the code to the point where the checkboxes are rendered correctly.

But I don't know what to do after that. Once checkboxes are rendered, I need the values of the checkboxes to initialize an object (which would be part of state) that is a key value pair of `{checkboxName1:false, checkboxName2:false}`. Then as the checkboxes are selected the object would be updated. So if `checkboxName1` was checked by the user, then the object would be updated to: `{checkboxName1:true, checkboxName2:false}`

Then I need the data from the entire form (Q1 and Q2) to be saved with the form's Submit button. The data from 2nd question will be used to drive output on another screen.

This issue seems to be the closest to what I am looking for: [How to set input value of one field based on another field in formik?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61347453/how-to-set-input-value-of-one-field-based-on-another-field-in-formik) but they are only using input from Q1 to drive output (not further inputs) of Q2 in their form.

This is my basic code:

```
  const initialValues = {
    selectedCategory: "",
  };



function handleSubmit() {
    console.log("Handle submit");
  }



function buildIngredientsChoice(groceryCategory) {
    console.log(groceryCategory);

    const ingredientsInChosenCategory = indgredientCategories.filter(
      (each) => each.category === groceryCategory
    );

    //Middle ground:
    const justArrayOfIngredients =
      ingredientsInChosenCategory[0]["ingredients"];

    // Build obj of ingredients:
    const objOfIngredientsCheckboxes = ingredientsInChosenCategory[0][
  "ingredients"
].reduce((o, key) => ({ ...o, [key]: false }), {});

console.log(justArrayOfIngredients);

return justArrayOfIngredients.map((each, index) => (
  <CommonCheckbox key={index} title={each}></CommonCheckbox>
));}



<Formik initialValues={initialValues} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          {(formik) => (
            <>
              <View>
                <Picker
                  // passing value directly from formik
                  selectedValue={formik.values.selectedCategory}
                  // changing value in formik
                  onValueChange={(itemValue) =>
                    formik.setFieldValue("selectedCategory", itemValue)
                  }
                >
                  <Picker.Item
                    label="Select your category"
                    value={initialValues.selectedCategory}
                    key={0}
                  />

                  <Picker.Item label="Produce" value="produce" key={1} />
                  //A bunch of items in Picker. 
              </View>
                //This renders the checkboxes correctly but that's where U get stuck: 
              {formik.values.selectedCategory
                ? buildIngredientsChoice(formik.values.selectedCategory)
                : null}
              {/* submitting formik instead of calling this.handleSubmit directly */}
              <Button title="Submit" onPress={formik.handleSubmit} />
            </>
          )}
        </Formik>
```

If you have Expo app downloaded on an Android phone, you can view the app here: https://expo.io/@sabbygirl99/recipe-project-mobile

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I guess is with submitting your form. You've to bind `submitForm` event handler with button click:

```
<Button title="Submit" onPress={formik.submitForm} />
```

The other thing is you have to bind `onChange` or `setFieldValue` with checkboxes as well. And I think you should render checkboxes (which you're already doing) but store an ingredient in an array when value of checkbox is `true`.

```
const initialValues = {
    selectedCategory: "",
};



function handleSubmit(values) {
    console.log("Handle submit", values);
}



function buildIngredientsChoice(groceryCategory, setFieldValue) {
    console.log(groceryCategory);

    const ingredientsInChosenCategory = indgredientCategories.filter(
      (each) => each.category === groceryCategory
    );

    //Middle ground:
    const justArrayOfIngredients =
      ingredientsInChosenCategory[0]["ingredients"];

    // Build obj of ingredients:
    const objOfIngredientsCheckboxes = ingredientsInChosenCategory[0][
  "ingredients"
].reduce((o, key) => ({ ...o, [key]: false }), {});

console.log(justArrayOfIngredients);

return justArrayOfIngredients.map((each, index) => (
  <CommonCheckbox key={index} title={each} onChange={val => {
    setFieldValue(`ingredients.someCheckbox${index}`, val)
  }}></CommonCheckbox>
));}



<Formik initialValues={initialValues} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          {(formik) => (
            <>
              <View>
                <Picker
                  // passing value directly from formik
                  selectedValue={formik.values.selectedCategory}
                  // changing value in formik
                  onValueChange={(itemValue) =>
                    formik.setFieldValue("selectedCategory", itemValue)
                  }
                >
                  <Picker.Item
                    label="Select your category"
                    value={initialValues.selectedCategory}
                    key={0}
                  />

                  <Picker.Item label="Produce" value="produce" key={1} />
                  //A bunch of items in Picker. 
              </View>
                //This renders the checkboxes correctly but that's where U get stuck: 
              {formik.values.selectedCategory &&
                  buildIngredientsChoice(formik.values.selectedCategory, formik.setFieldValue)
              }
              <Button title="Submit" onPress={formik.submitForm} />
            </>
          )}
        </Formik>
```